# How can I filter out a get request of all users in my DB so that users with an admin role are not shown in the list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am building a spring boot application that allows an admin to view a list of all users saved in my Database. However, at the moment, all users including the ones with an admin role are being displayed. I was suggested to filter out admins in the backend code but I am not sure how to go about doing this. If anyone could help me, it would very much appreciated. Thank you! (I am using JPA + Hibernate)

**UPDATE:**
I was suggested a solution that was very useful below. I needed to make a `getUsers` method which queries data from my Database in a way that filters out admins. At first, I was having issues with the SQL part of the query since I am using hibernate (I think, correct me if I am wrong). I was made aware that you can't use a JPQL query to access raw entity data from tables, ***since I was using @JoinTable to create my user_roles table that doesn't have an entity class for it, I was confused.*** Seen in my `User` class as follows:

```html
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

I was receiving a red line in my user repository class at user_role ur in `FROM User u,Role r, user_role ur`. Futhermore, I was receiving the following error: `user_role is not mapped [SELECT u.id,u.username,u.email FROM com.Application.models.User u,com.Application.models.Role r, user_role ur WHERE u.id=ur.id AND r.id=ur.id AND r.name<>'ADMIN']`. My Role entity is used to map the role ID and the role name whereas my user_role table contains a column of the user ID and the role ID in one table for mapping the user id to a role id. That is where my last error was.

**My Solution**:

```html
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u join u.roles r WHERE NOT EXISTS" + "(SELECT r FROM u.roles WHERE r.name = 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
    List<User> getUsers();
```

This succesfuly filtered out users with an admin role in my case. I hope this helps someone one day, I was stuck on this for a minute. Thanks for all the help!

User.java:

```html
package com.Application.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),


        })

public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(); 

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserPost> userPosts = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String username, String email
                ,String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

TestController.java:

```html
package com.Application.controller;

import com.Application.models.User;
import com.Application.repository.UserPostsRepository;
import com.Application.repository.UserProfileRepository;
import com.Application.repository.UserRepository;
import com.Application.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.Application.security.services.UserDetailsService;
import com.Application.security.services.UserPostService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {
    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "authorization";

    @Autowired
    private final UserPostsRepository userPostRepo;
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    private final UserProfileRepository userProfRepo;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private UserPostService userPostService;
    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    public TestController(UserPostsRepository userPostRepo, UserRepository userRepo, UserProfileRepository userProfRepo) {
        this.userPostRepo = userPostRepo;
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.userProfRepo = userProfRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public Content.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String userAccess() {
        return "User Content.";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/mod")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MODERATOR')")
    public String moderatorAccess() {
        return "Moderator Board.";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public List<User> adminAccess(Model model) {
        List<User> allUsers = userRepo.getUsers();
        allUsers.forEach(user -> model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername()));

        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

Role.java:

```html
package com.Application.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private ERole name;
    public Role() {
    }
    public Role(ERole name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ERole getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(ERole name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ERole.java:

```html
package com.Application.models;

public enum ERole {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_MODERATOR,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```html
package com.Application.repository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.Application.models.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    User findUserById(Long id);

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    List<User> findAll();

      @Query("SELECT u.id,u.username,u.email FROM User u,Role r, user_role ur WHERE u.id=ur.id AND r.id=ur.id AND r.name<>\'ADMIN\'") //Error at users u, roles r, user_roles ur even though the table names are right
    List<User> getUsers();

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
```

RoleRepository.java:

```html
package com.Application.repository;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.Application.models.ERole;
import com.Application.models.Role;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Optional<Role> findByName(ERole name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this but here is a simple way.Just add the below method in your repository interface

```
@Query("SELECT u.firstname,u.lastname,u.email FROM user u,role r,user_role ur WHERE u.id=ur.user_id AND r.id=ur.role_id AND r.name<>\'ADMIN\'")
List<User> getUsers();
```

getUsers() retuns a list of users except admin users.
Of course you can change the query depending on what columns are in user table and change user_roles with the name of the appropriate table in your database.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you know if this will work if im using JPA and hibernate with entity models? I attempted your solution with my column names but am receiving red lines on `FROM users u,roles r,user_roles` for some reason. I updated my question with more details on the user and role code. Any idea?

Comment: Just use class names instead of table names. For example if your entity class is User you can do something like ```FROM User user```(you can use user as an object) and to select columns use fields in your entity class like the way you access class field using an object like ```user.firstName```.

Comment: perfect! I saw someone suggest something similar and now I was able to figure out most of my error but I have one more left. I have a table "role" that is created from my Role entity class and it contains a column for the role id and the name of the role itself. However as you can see in my User class, I also have another table `user_roles`, but here is the catch. I do not have an entity class for this table, so that is the last error I am getting in ` @Query("SELECT u.id,u.username,u.email FROM User u,Role r, user_role ur WHERE u.id=ur.user_id AND r.id=ur.role.id AND r.name<>\'ADMIN\'")`

Comment: So I guess my question would now be: How can I access the table if I do not have an entity class for it?